# Mime encoding of mail header lines with Perl broken in 5.26

Tags: perl, email, email-headers

We use Perl to encode correct mail header lines. With the new version v5.26.2 we encounter the following problem, here simplified in a few lines:

```
$ cat mime.pl

use strict;
use utf8;
use Encode;

print "$^V", "\n";
my $encoded = Encode::encode('MIME-Q', 'To: Blödmann <guru@sisis.de>');
print "$encoded", "\n";
```

v5.16.2:

```
$ /usr/local/sisis-pap/perl5.16.2/bin/perl mime.pl
v5.16.2
To:=?UTF-8?Q?=20Bl=C3=B6dmann=20?=<guru@sisis.de>
```

v5.26.2:

```
$ /usr/local/sisis-pap/bin/perl mime.pl
v5.26.2
=?UTF-8?Q?To=3A_Bl=C3=B6dmann_=3Cguru=40sisis=2Ede=3E?=
```

i.e. with v5.26.2 the full line is encoded as quoted printable (and will not be understood by sendmail. In v5.16.2 only the word "Blödman" with the UTF-8 German Umlaut was encoded, the mail addr itself was left in peace.

How is this supposed to be fixed?

Comment: Have you looked at Encode's source code yet to try to pin down when a change was made that introduced this new behaviour?

Comment: At least in Encode v2.84, the "old" behaviour of not encoding `To:` was present. But the documentation and behaviour changed, and it (now) says _However, it cannot be used directly for the whole header with the field name or for the structured header fields like `From`, `To`, `Cc`, `Message-Id`, etc... _ , so my recommendation is you review your code and adapt to it. Diff from 2.84 to current: https://metacpan.org/diff/file?target=DANKOGAI/Encode-2.98/lib%2FEncode%2FMIME%2FHeader.pm&source=DANKOGAI%2FEncode-2.84%2Flib%2FEncode%2FMIME%2FHeader.pm

Answer (score 2):

The output in 5.16.2 doesn't follow the [RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) and only Perl can parse it back to the original header.

Use [Email::MIME::Header::AddressList](http://p3rl.org/Email::MIME::Header::AddressList) instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

use Email::MIME::Header::AddressList;

my $unicode_addresses = 'Blödmann <guru@sisis.de>, Großmann <guru@example.com>';
my $mime_encoded_addresses = 'Email::MIME::Header::AddressList'
    ->from_string($unicode_addresses)
    ->as_mime_string();

print "To: $mime_encoded_addresses\n";
```

Output:

```
To: =?UTF-8?B?QmzDtmRtYW5u?= <guru@sisis.de>, =?UTF-8?B?R3Jvw59tYW5u?= <guru@example.com>
```

See [Encode::MIME::Header](http://p3rl.org/Encode::MIME::Header) on how to use Encode with MIME-* properly.